# PCB/SCH Design: Fuse w/ Holder

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, fuses, fuse-holders

How would one go about creating a library component for a through-hole fuse that sits in a holder? The part in question is this:

Fuse: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/37202000411/WK4234BK-ND/245312
Fuse Holder: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/56000001009/WK6235-ND/808503

I was thinking of going about it the way I go about DIP ICs that I need to be socketed, which is by adding the IC to the schematic, and simply putting "Socketed" in the comments/notes in the Bill of Materials. However, the above fuse/fuse holder is not standard (as far as I can tell), so I am wondering how others would go about this? Would it be acceptable to use the fuse in the schematic and in a comments/notes section of the BOM say "Socketed, Littlefuse P/N 56000001009" or something similar?

Just wondering if there is a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it as with a socketed IC like you are describing.

- Fuse symbol to the schematic with a comment that its socketed.
  [image]
- BoM for PCBA shows the socket for F7.
- [optional] The actual fuse is in the BoM for top assembly (or some higher subassembly).  Plugging in the fuse is a separate operation.  It's also possible that slightly different versions of the product may have different fuses.

Comment: This, which an annotation for socket and fuse part numbers. I've seen it cause confusion.

Comment: Great, that's what I was leaning towards (a combination of Option 1 and Option 2). I am using Altium, so I have added custom component parameters which I export to the BOM. I have one called "Notes", in which I will mention that it is socketed using the Littelfuse P/N, and tick the box making it visible on the schematic. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but just for keeping track of this, I decided to add my findings here.... I had a similar dilemma i.e. fuse holder and a fuse. You need both on the schematic and on the BOM so I found that the easiest way would be to create a symbol/partnumber for the fuse and a symbol/partnumber for the fuse holder. The fuse symbol would be created with no pins so as not to cause a problem within the capture tool. The two symbols would then overlap one another. See images. The end result would be that the fuse and fuse holder are on the BOM

[image: fuse holder and fuse independent]

[image: fuseholder and fuse overlapping]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am late to the party and didn't see this earlier.

The crux of the matter is that people don't understand that the schematic for a PCB is often a cut-set or subset of the PCBA schematic and would have different drawing numbers, as the P/N for the PCB would be different from the P/N for the PCB assembly.

A fuse with a fuse holder or fuse clips is a case in point. On the PCBA schematic you would show both the fuse, with ref des of F#, and the fuse socket, with ref des of XF# or fuse clips with ref des of XF#A and XF#B. Thus your parts list (PL) is complete. F is the class letter for a fuse and X is the class letter for a socket, in this case a fuse holder. See IEEE 315 Clause 22.4 for official/standard list of class letters.

I would use the IEC 60617/IEEE 315A Clause 9.1.1 symbol (the one marked with IEC--it is a rectangle with a line running through it). Then on either end of the fuse I would show a female contact symbol per IEC 60617/IEEE 315A Clause 5.3.1 (the marked "Add: OR IEC"). If fuse clips then use ref des XF#A and XF#B. If a single fuse holder then use a mechanical linkage line connecting the two socket symbols and use the ref des XF#. For the PCB schematic you would copy over the PCBA schematic and delete the fuse as there is no land pattern/footprint for it and you won't get an error message when doing a DRC.